# MVC4 Ajax request and loss of browser state

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have a MVC4 application. A served page have multiple items with typical "Add to favorites" link to it. Something like ->

`[page 1]
...[item1][Add to favorites]
...[item2][Add to favorites]`

"Add to favorites" is a Ajax actionlink which connects to the backend. The backend basically maintains a list of favorited items in Httpcontext.Session. A JSON response "true/false" is sent back to client. If 'true' the client code changes "Add to favorites" link to "Favorited". Something like:

`[page 1]
...[item1][Favorited]
...[item2][Add to favorites]`

Now if I visit another page, say Page x, and come back to [page 1] after that, I see

`[page 1]
...[item1][Add to favorites]
...[item2][Add to favorites]`

instead of

`[page 1]
...[item1][Favorited]
...[item2][Add to favorites]`

I'm wondering if there's a way to display the true state. Thanks.

Comment: Are you storing all "Add favorite" actions on the sever side?

Comment: So when you load the following page, did you look in the session and see what was in there?  Was it empty? Are they stored in the key you thought it was stored in?

Comment: It was not empty. It had the favorited items.

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the page, you will need to get a list of the favorite items and render the links according to that data.

There are a few different ways you could do this. Since you are using mvc, it would probably be easiest to load a list of favorites items as part of the view model and render the view accordingly.

Comment: During reloading, the browser happens to serve cached content; thus no backend request. Weird enough, it doesn't cache the stae of the favorited items.